# Eclipse changes to PHP perspective after running code in Java

Tags: eclipse

whenever I try to run something in Java, Eclipse changes into the PHP perspective. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gogo Window->Preferences, select Run/Debug->Perspectives.

Make sure that under "Java application" you dont have PHP perspective on the right.

Comment: It was set to none so I set it to Java but after restarting eclipse it's still the same :/

Comment: Strange. Can you try to create another workspace and see if it happens there also?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: Whenever a java program terminated, it would switch to the PHP perspective, even if it was closed.

It was caused by my debug configuration for PHP. Goto PHP->Run/Debug->Workspace Options. I had selected "Always" under  "Switch back to the PHP perspective when debugging has terminated". Apparently, PDT isn't smart enough to descriminate between different kinds of launches, and assumes all launches are PHP.